# Finding the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1 + x^3 + x^8)^{10}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, ring-theory, generating-functions

> Find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1 + x^3 + x^8)^{10}$.

I've tried thinking of this combinatorially, but I couldn't get it to make sense. I've also tried applying some identities, only to lead to dead ends. Any hints?

Comment: Which coefficient?

Comment: @rlgordonma Thanks

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Can you write $25$ as a sum of eights and threes?

Comment: How does the 10 play a role?

Comment: @AlanH The 10 tells you how many choices you have as to where you can "place" each 8 and 3. Azimut has provided a more full solution.

Answer (score 5):

"The only way to form an $x^{25}$ term is to gather two $x^8$ and three $x^3$ . Since there are ${{10}\choose{2}} =45$ ways
to choose two $x^8$ from the $10$ multiplicands and $8$ ways to choose three  ${{8}\choose{3}}= 56$ ways to choose $x^3$ from the remaining $8$
multiplicands, the answer is $45×56 = 2520$." Same as asimut with slightly different wording.

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out where the $8$ in ${{8}\choose{3}}$ was coming from. The 3 $x^3$ are being chosen from the *remaining* $8$ multiplicands. ${10\choose{3}} {7\choose{2}}$ would also be an identical solution.

Answer (score 3):

The exponent 25 can arise as $2\cdot 8 + 3\cdot 3 + 5\cdot 0$ only. So you have to count the words of length $10$ consisting of two 8's, three 3's and five 0's. Basic combinatorics gives the result $$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3} = 2520\text{.}$$