# find the coefficient of $x^{25}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(x+ 2x^{2} + 3x^{3} +..) (x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+..)^{6}$

when I'm taking $x$ out I'm getting a coefficient of $x^{19}$ .. 
Can someone give a hand please? thanks

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307939/finding-the-coefficient-of-x25-in-1-x3-x810), more or less.

Comment: Yeah ive looked at it and its not helping me much :\ @DietrichBurde

Comment: Have you tried to find the other posts about it? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989862/find-the-coefficient-of-x24-in-1-x-x2-x3-x4-x58/989889), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344095/find-coefficient-of-x2-in-a-complicated-expansion?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003055/find-the-coefficient-of-x16-in-expansion-of-x25x64x36x211x63?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623272/find-coefficient-of-x20?rq=1) and several other links.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yeah ive looked but in my question its endless and in these links its little bit different

Comment: No, it's not endless, because almost all products then would have exponent $x^n$ with $n$ much bigger than $25$. So all terms $x^m$ for $m$ big enough will no longer contribute to the coefficient of $x^{25}$.

Comment: In your last edit you heavily changed the difficulty of the task. Is that power $6$ and the start at power $3$ in the second factor now correct? (But then again the power $x^{19}$ now makes sense.)

Comment: @LutzL Yes now its as it should be i didnt notice that the six got away

Answer (score 3):

Using generating functions, the coefficient we’re interested in is $$[x^{25}]\left(x\frac d{dx}\frac1{1-x}\right)\left({x^3\over1-x}\right)^6 = [x^{25}]{x\over(1-x)^2}{x^{18}\over(1-x)^6} = [x^6]{1\over(1-x)^8} = \binom{13}6.$$ The last equality comes from the [generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

To systematically solve this question, you need to use the binomial series, which is an extension of the binomial theorem to negative integer powers. Starting with the *geometric series*, which you should recognize in the second factor, 
$$
(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...
$$
you get
$$
(1-x)^{-d}=(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)^d=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+d-1}{d-1}x^n
\\
=1+dx+\frac{d(d+1)}2x^2+\frac{d(d+1)(d+2)}6x^3+...
$$
Especially you can recognize that the first factor can be identified as
$$
x+2x^2+3x^3+... = x(1-x)^{-2}.
$$

Then the product is equal to 
$$
x^{1+6\cdot 3}(1-x)^{-2-6}=x^{19}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+7}{7}x^n,
$$ 
so that the coefficient you need to evaluate is 
$$
\binom{13}7=\binom{13}6=\frac{13⋅12⋅11⋅10⋅9⋅8}{1⋅2⋅3⋅4⋅5⋅6}=13⋅12⋅11=1716.
$$

Comment: I would like to send you a pic of what i did because im stuck.. i have: x^19(1+2x+3x^2..)(1+x+x^2..) and im stuck

Answer (score 0):

**After OP's edit.**

Hint 1: It is equivalent to:
$$[x^{25}](x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots)(x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots)^{\color{red}6}=\\
[x^{25}]x^{19}(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^6=\\
[x^6](1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^6$$

Hint2: The pairs of powers of $x$ are:
$$(0,6),(1,5),(2,4),...,(6,0)$$
Hint 3:
$$[x^6](1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^6=\\
[x^6](1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)(1-x)^{-6}\stackrel{*}=\\
[x^6](1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {5+i\choose i}x^i=\\
\small{1\cdot {11\choose 6}+2\cdot {10\choose 5}+3\cdot {9\choose 4}+4\cdot {8\choose 3}+5\cdot {7\choose 2}+6\cdot {6\choose 1}+7\cdot {5\choose 0}}= 1716.$$
Note: At $\stackrel{*}=$, it was used [Negative binomial theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html).

Comment: im sorry but i dont follow

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is $$S(x)=[(x+2x^2+5x^3+...)(x^3+x^5+x^4+...)^6]= \left(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \frac{x^{18}}{(1-x)^{6}}\right)=\left(\frac{x^{19}}{(1-x)^8}\right).$$
Then coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $S(x)$ is the co-efficient of $x^6$ in $(1-x)^{-8}$ which by infinite binomial series is ${-8 \choose 6}={13 \choose 6}.$ Note that $$(1+z)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {-n \choose k} ~z^k, ~|z|<1$$

$${-n \choose k}=(-1)^k {n+k-1 \choose k}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+ 2x^{2} + 3x^{3} +..) (x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+..)^{6}$$
$$=x^{18}\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^6}$$
$$=x^{19}\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^8}$$

The generating function $$\frac1{(1-x)^k}=\sum_\limits{n=k-1}^\infty \binom{n}{k-1}x^{n-k+1}$$

means we want $n-8+1=6$, and so $n=13$.

Therefore the answer is $\binom{13}{8-1}=1716$.